# Vb2010 Excel Not saving

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i currently have a form and a button. when i click the button, it creates an excel spread sheet and adds "hi" to range("A1"). The problem is that i am trying to save and close the file but it still prompts me "If i would like to save", is there s way i can get rid of this message? is it not saving for some reason?

i am using the code:

```
xlWorkbook.save()
Excelapp.quit()
```

i have also tried using the code below but it still doesn't work:

```
me.excelapp.displayalerts=false
```

for some reason it does not want to be saved

> Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
>
> ```
> Dim ExcelApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
> Dim WB As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
> Dim WS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
> ```
>
> sub button1()     WB = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("Path_To_File")
>           WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
>
> ```
>     'code to change some values here and there
>
>     WB.Save()
>     ExcelApp.Quit() end sub
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The SaveAs works fine for me...

```
 WB.SaveAs("filename.xls", True)
```